# How to add nullterm to end of mmap() output?

Tags: arrays, c, string, posix, mmap

In general, how would I go about adding a nullterm to the end of a mmap() output, so that I can treat it like a string? Before this gets flagged, I do *not* want to modify the original file. I'm trying to get the entire file as a string, but the lack of a nullterm `\0` on the end makes any normal string operations extremely difficult. Since string literals are stored in read-only memory, and there isn't really a way to change the size of that, how would I go about it?

```c
      int fd = fileno(fp);            // convert FILE struct to file descriptor
      char *src = mmap(0, file_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
```

This is the basis of my program. I'm attempting numerous file operations on it, but doing anything with the last character of the output ends up printing random value from memory, since there's no nullterm.

Comment: The simple solution is to not use string functions that do not also accept a length parameter. So don't use `strlen` but use `strnlen`, etc. And use the field width format specifier in `printf` like e.g. `%*s`

Comment: That's the issue. Even if I try printing the last char in the "string" with printf("%c"), it still prints out random garbage afterwards.

Comment: I apologise, I should have said `%.*s`.

Comment: what is that doing?

Comment: It is somewhat cryptically described in the manual page: `If the precision is given as just '.', the precision is taken to be zero.` and `the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions`. and `Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the precision is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type int.`, but in short it just allows for no more characters to be processed than the number specified.

Comment: I see. That seems like a very complicated solution for just adding a nullterm on the end. I'm trying to write a wrapper function for it, but it doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: You could map it `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE`.  You can then write null bytes wherever you please and they will not be written back to the file.

Answer (score -2):

I figured out a workaround. I wrote a function that just returns the same string, but with a nullterm at the end. It doesn't modify the original, and it's not efficient by any means, but it works for what I need to do. I'm a student and don't have time to write the most artistically and logically perfect C code, so here's code that *works*.

This function needs the size of the string for reference, so for anyone in the future who's having my problem except you don't know the size of the string, then you're out of luck

```c
// s: string to add nullterm to
// sz: size of string.
char *add_nullterm(char *s, int sz) {
  int new_sz = sz + 1;
  char temp[new_sz];

  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    temp[i] = s[i];
  }
  temp[sz] = '\0';

  char *out = (char*)temp;
  return out;
}
```

Comment: You return a pointer to the local array `temp`, whose lifetime expires when your function returns.  When the caller dereferences that pointer, it causes undefined behavior.  So if this code "*works*" it is purely by chance.

Comment: (Nothing personal with the downvote, but I think it's important as a signal to other readers that this is not a solution they should use.)

Comment: how would you fix it?

Comment: The usual ways are either to have the caller provide a pointer to a buffer of sufficient size, or else to have your function allocate memory with `malloc` and ensure that the caller `free`s it when finished.  That said, I agree with the previous comments that the best solution is probably to redesign the code that uses the data, so that it does not require a null terminator, but instead is given an explicit length.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing anyways, I just have to avoid using standard library functions since virtually all of them rely on a nullterm

Comment: Often you just need to use *different* library functions.  Instead of `strcpy`, use `memcpy`.  Instead of `strchr`, use `memchr`.  Instead of `printf` or `fputs`, use `fwrite`.  Etc.